# How do I add more colors to the bookcover class (package xcolor)

Tags: color, bookcover

I am struggling to add more colors to the bookcover class.

Here is my code sample:

```
  \documentclass[
        coverwidth=145mm,
        coverheight=211mm,
        spinewidth=8mm,
        flapwidth=9cm,
        wrapwidth=1mm,
        bleedwidth=3mm
                    ]{bookcover}
    
      
    \newbookcovercomponenttype{center rotate}{
        \vfill
        \centering
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{#1}
        \vfill}
         
    \usepackage[outline]{contour}
    \contourlength{1pt}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{kantlipsum,microtype}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    
       
    \begin{document}

    \begin{bookcover}
    \begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{bg whole}
        color=cyan
    \end{bookcoverelement}

    ...
    
    \end{document}
```

I am using on of the predefined colors ("cyan"). But I would need more colors than the beasic colors. But if I try to extend the colors available via adding

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
```

I get the error message that the package has already been loaded with option []. I tried with all the other sets, i.e. "svgnames/svgnames*" etc. but with the same result.

What can I do to get more options for colors within the bookcover?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 3):

The document class `bookcover` obviously already loads the `xcolor` package with no options, so you will get an error if you try to load the package again with other options.

But you can add the option `dvipsnames` (or `svgnames`) to the options for `\documentclass` and it will be forwarded to the `xcolor` package when it is loaded by the document class:

```
\documentclass[
    coverwidth=145mm,
    coverheight=211mm,
    spinewidth=8mm,
    flapwidth=9cm,
    wrapwidth=1mm,
    bleedwidth=3mm,
    dvipsnames
]{bookcover}

\begin{document}
\begin{bookcover}
\begin{bookcoverelement}{color}{bg whole}
    color=MidnightBlue
\end{bookcoverelement}
\end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Jasper, thank you! If I do as you suggest I get the follwing error: "! Package calc Errod 'd' invalid at this point. ... 1.101 ...ength{\bleedwidth}{\bookcover@bleedwidth}" and it continuers with missing \begin{document}".

Comment: The missing comma. Sorry, I got it.

Comment: @Rodion Yes, this error is probably due to a missing comma in the options list before `dvipsnames`.

Comment: If this is for a printed (to paper) cover, be aware that the printed colors may look somewhat different than what you see on the computer monitor. If you have a graphics program that lets you view an image in softproof mode, that is good. GIMP can do it. Regardless of the actual print technology, the color profile FOGRA39L is approximately correct, except that very dark colors may not print as dark as expected.